# How to fix CSRF TOKEN ERROR while fetching data to Jtable in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, csrf, jquery-jtable

I am using Jtable in laravel but facing CSRF TOKEN ERROR on it. 
How to add csrftokenValue in my Post function ?

**My route look like this:**

```
Route::post('test_list', function() {
$tests = LabTest::all()->toArray();
$result = array(
    'Result' => 'OK',
    'Records' => $tests
);
return $result;
});
Route::post('/test_create', function() {
    LabTest::create(array(
        'Name' => Input::get('Name'),
        'Remark' => Input::get('Remark'),
    ));
    $result = array(
        'Result' => 'OK',
        'Records' => Input::all()
    );
    return $result;
```

Comment: your POST request must come with CSRF token attached to it. Hoping that you are posting data with javascript, add the CSRF token using Session::token() to your javascript code.

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using ajax. If you are using jquery for ajax request, then you might want to include [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) in those requests.

Add a meta tag for laravel token

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And set jquery ajax properties to use the above.

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
</script>
```

Take a look at [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf)